# Saleforce SOQL query - Jersey Readtimeout error

Tags: salesforce, soql

I'm having a problem on a batch job that has a simple SOQL query that returns a lot of records. More than a million. 
The query, as it is, cannot be optimized much further according to SOQL best practices. (At least, as far as I know. I'm not an SF SOQL expert.)

The problem is that I'm getting -

```
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

I try bumping up the Jersey readtime out value from 30 seconds to 60 seconds, but it still times out.

Any recommendation on how to deal with this issue? Any recommended value for the readtimeout parameter for a query that returns that much data?

The query is like this:

> SELECT Id, field1, field2__c, field3__c, field3__c  FROM Object__c
>   WHERE field2__c = true AND (not field3 like '\u0025Some string\u0025')
>   ORDER BY field4__c ASC

Comment: Are you using the Bulk API?

Comment: No, I was starting to think about that as an option. Do you recommend it?

Comment: (My answer was rightly critiqued as mistaken/simplified incorrectly, but I still recommend the Bulk API)

Answer (score 0):

In no specific order...

- Batches written in Apex time out after 2 minutes so maybe set same in your Java application
- Run your query in Developer Console using the [query plan](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334796&type=1&mode=1) feature (you probably will have to put real `%` in there, not `\u0025`). Pay attention which part has "Cost" column > 1.
- what are field types? Plain checkbox and text or some complex formulas?
- Is that text static or changes depending on what your app needs? would you consider filtering out the string in your code rather than SOQL? Counter-intuitive to return more records than you really need but well, might be an option.
- would you consider making a formula field with either whole logic or just the string search and then [asking SF to index the formula](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000325247&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1). Or maybe making another field (another checkbox?) with "yes, it contains that text" info, set the value by workflow maybe (essentially prepare your data a bit to efficiently query it later)
- read up about [skinny tables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.meta/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp/ldv_deployments_infrastructure_skinny_tables.htm) and see if it's something that could work for you (needs SF support)
- can you make an analytic snapshot of your data (make a report, make SF save results to helper object, query that object)? Even if it'd just contain lookups to your original source so you'll access always fresh values it could help. Might be a storage killer though
- have you considered "[big objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bigobjects.meta/bigobjects/async_query_overview.htm)" and async soql
- I'm not proud of it but in the past I had some success badgering the SF database. Not via API but if I had a nightly batch job that was timing out I kept resubmitting it and eventually 3rd-5th time it managed to start. Something in the query optimizer, creation of cursor in underlying Oracle database, caching partial results... I don't know.
- what's in the `ORDER BY`? Some date field? If you need records updated since X first then maybe [replication API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/calls_for_data_replication.htm) could help getting ids first.
- does it make sense to use `LIMIT 200` for example? Which API you're using, SOAP or REST? Might be that returning smaller chunks (SOAP: [batch size](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.220.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_changing_batch_size.htm), REST API: [special header](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/headers_queryoptions.htm)) would help it finish faster.
- when all else fails (but do contact SF support, make sure you exhausted the options) maybe restructure the whole thing. Make SF push data to you whenever it changes, not pull. There's "Streaming API" (CometD implementation, Bayeux protocol, however these are called) and "Change Data Capture" and "Platform Events" for nice event bus-driven architecture decisions, replaying old events up to 3 days back if the client was down and couldn't listen... But that's a totally different topic.

Comment: Thanks @eyescream for all the info. I really appreciate it. Lots of options to think about. 
Let me share more details: 
- This batch job is written in Java. 
- I had already run the query in the Developer Console. No costs > 1. 
- The fields are all date fields except for the one that is being compared to the String. This field is a picklist field. 
- The order by is on a date type field. 
- I'm using REST api.

Comment: Dates and picklists can be indexed by SF support, text fields you could index yourself. I'd say raise a case either way, they'll know better. Including things like "i have index on field A and B but that doesn't mean it'll be considered in query that filters on both"